# How to solve a non-linear integral equation?

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

I have a non-linear integral equation that I'd like to solve with *Mathematica*:

$$ \int_{0}^{1} \mathrm{d}x \frac{B(x) v}{(B(x) + B(v))^2} = 1$$

```
Solve[Integrate[B[x] v / (B[x] + B[v])^2, {x, 0, 1}] == 1, B[v], {v}]
```

This problem comes up in an exotic problem from auction theory where I want to find the optimal bidding function `B[v]` for `v` in `[0,1]`.  Is there any way to get a solution to this problem in *Mathematica*? Closed-form solutions are preferred (duh!) but a plot of a numerical one is also OK.

Comment: Mathematica doesn't have any functionality for solving Integral equations. They  must, if possible, be first converted to differential equations. You could numerically solve the equation by putting it in the form B'[v] = f[v] where f[v] is a function of v that has an integral somewhere in it, but that doesn't look possible in this case.

Comment: @Searke OK, thanks for the info.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Let me show how to roll your own numerical solution to a non-linear integral equation using a [collocation method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_method). It's fun!

This will involve two approximations. First, we will approximate the function `B[x]` by its values at `n` particular points in the range `{x, 0, 1}`. The integral over `x` will be replaced by a weighted sum over `n`, i.e., a quadrature rule. Second, we will only exactly satisfy the integral equation at those `n` points. It will hopefully be approximately satisfied at other points.

**Quadrature rule**

Let's borrow one of [NIntegrate's quadrature rules](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationRules.html):

```
order = 5;
{abscissae, weights, errweights} = 
 NIntegrate`GaussKronrodRuleData[order, MachinePrecision]
```

[image]

The first part `abscissae` is the list of `n` points in the range `{0, 1}` at which we will approximate the solution. The second part `weights` is the vector of weights for function values at those points to compute an integral estimate.

```
n = Length[abscissae]
```

[image]

**Approximate integral equation**

Using the weights of the quadrature rule we can define the approximate integral equation at a single point:

```
integralEquation[vals_, v_, fv_] := -1 + 
  weights.Table[fx v/(fx + fv)^2, {fx, vals}]
```

Here `vals` is the list of function values at the abscissae, representing the function `B[x]` in your question, and `v` and `fv` are particular values of `v` and `B[v]` in your question.

The value of the above function is zero when the integral equation is approximately satisfied at the specified point.

Here is a vector-valued version that evaluates the approximate integral equation at all of the abscissae:

```
integralEquation[vals_] := 
 MapThread[integralEquation[vals, ##] &, {abscissae, vals}]
```

Given the vector of function values at the absissae, it gives the vector of residuals indicating whether the integral equation is satisified:

```
integralEquation[RandomReal[1, n]]
```

[image]

We would like to find `vals` such that the residuals are all zero! I.e., we want to find a root of `integralEquation`.

**Find root**

Let's use the symbols `{c[1], ..., c[n]}` to represent the solved function values at the abscissae:

```
vars = Array[c, n]
```

[image]

We will find a root using [FindRoot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindRoot.html), which likes to have a decent guess for the values of the `c[i]` to start with. By experimenting a little I learned that a linear solution of the form `B[x]==0.2*x` is a decent guess:

```
guess = Thread[{vars, 0.2 abscissae}]
```

[image]

Now we can search for a root of `integralEquation`:

```
solution = FindRoot[integralEquation[vars], guess]
```

[image]

This represents an approximate solution to the integral equation.

**Solution function**

We can plot the approximate solution over the whole range `{0, 1}` by interpolating the solution we just obtained at the abscissae:

```
f[x_] = InterpolatingPolynomial[Thread[{abscissae, vars}] /. solution, x];
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

The solution is not exactly correct. In fact, for very small values of `x`, the residual (the amount by which the integral equation is not satisfied) is substantial. Plot the residual for a few values of `x`:

```
residual[f_, v_] := 
 Module[{x}, -1 + NIntegrate[f[x] v/(f[x] + f[v])^2, {x, 0, 1}]];
ListLinePlot[Table[{x, residual[f, x]}, {x, 0.01, 1, 0.01}], 
 Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All, AxesStyle -> Dashed]
```

[image]

From here you have some options.

- You could increase the value of `n` (by increasing the value of `order`). You may run into issues with working precision (machine precision may not be enough). You could also use a local interpolation ([Interpolation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html)) instead of a global interpolation ([InterpolatingPolynomial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html)), which might be more stable for large `n`.
- You might be able to solve the tricky bit near `x==0` with other methods such as a power series expansion.

[Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1924102/IntegralEquationCollocationSolver.nb) is a notebook containing the above prototype.

**Linear integral equation**

For the benefit of people solving related problems, let me just mention that we used FindRoot to search for a root (starting from a plausible guess) because this is a *nonlinear* integral equation. For a *linear* integral equation, you can use the same collocation method, but the `integralEquations` will be linear, so you can be sure of finding a solution simply by using [Solve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html), or reformulate as a matrix problem and use [LinearSolve](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolve.html).

Comment: This is a great answer. +1

Comment: Wow... A really awesome answer, never expected such a level of detail! +1 and accepted. I think the `x=0` irregularity could be resolved by imposing `B[x]==0` (i.e. never bid for things one values at zero). If even that fails, `B'[x]>=0` (i.e. bids are monotonically increasing in the valuation) might give additional constraints on interpolating functions. Could you give a hint on how to impose such boundary conditions?

Comment: You could impose B[x]==0 as one of the n collocation points (a special case would be required for integralEquation to avoid appearing to divide by 0). A collocation point at the other endpoint would be fine too. Try LobattoKronrodRule for quadrature rules that include endpoints.

Comment: I will try that. Thanks again for this wonderful answer. I learnt a lot!

Comment: @AndrewMoylan Do you think the strategy suggested [here](http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v9i2/contents/IntegralEquations/IntegralEquations_5.html) of increasing the point's density near the interval endpoints could be of use here?

Comment: @belisarius Yes I think so. It's often a good way of handling singular points. Looking in the Mathematica Journal is a good idea! I do believe I saw a Mathematica package for integral equations at some point too.

Comment: Oh here is a Mathematica Journal article showing the linear case: http://www.mathematica-journal.com/issue/v8i4/tricks/contents/Tricks8-4_2.html

Comment: I couldn't get the `LobattoKronrodRule` to work. So in the end, I imposed the boundary condition `B[0]==0` at the very last step, in the interpolating polynomial.