# How do I solve a nonlinear Fredholm integral equation?

Tags: integral-equations

$u(x)= 1/3+\int_{0}^{1}x\,t\sqrt{u(t)}\,dt$

```
u[x] == 1/3 + Integrate[x t Sqrt[u[t]], {t, 0, 1}]
```

Any ideas on how to treat such a problem with *Mathematica* functions?

Comment: Have you seen [How to solve a non-linear integral equation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21062/how-to-solve-a-non-linear-integral-equation)

Comment: Greetings! Make the most of Mma.SE and **take the [tour] now**. **Help us to help you**, write an [excellent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). [Edit](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal** working examples of **code and data in [formatted form](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a Fredholm equation. Nevertheless it seems to have a simple solution. Indeed: one evidently finds the solution in the form

```
u[x_] := 1/3 + A*x;
```

where A is a constant to be determined later on. Substituting into the integral one finds:

```
Integrate[t Sqrt[u[t]], {t, 0, 1}]

(*  (2 (2 + (1 + 3 A)^(3/2) (-2 + 9 A)))/(135 Sqrt[3] A^2)  *)
```

This brings one to the equation imposed on A:

```
eq = (2 (2 + (1 + 3 A)^(3/2) (-2 + 9 A)))/(135 Sqrt[3] A^2) == A
```

This equation can be solved exactly:

```
Solve[eq,A]
```

But the result is so cumbersome, that (if you have no special reasons) it is better to solve it numerically:

```
sl = NSolve[(2 (2 + (1 + 3 A)^(3/2) (-2 + 9 A)))/(135 Sqrt[3] A^2) == 
   A, A]

{{A -> 0.382266}}
```

Thus, your result is  `u(x)=1/3+0.382x`

Have fun!